# does downsampling of big data in python bokeh server work? where documented?

Tags: server, bokeh, bigdata

Is there documentation how to program and use the bokeh server? There is a nice interactive web plot of 4gb of ocean data on youTube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-P3yA-P-sY

but I can not find any description how it was done. I have ~10Tbytes of data from the Greenbank radio telescope, and I would like to write something similar for exploring it.

The server documentation seems broken for this, if I look at
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/server.html#downsampling-with-server

it just goes in circles, there isn't anything there.

Can someone help with big data downsizing examples with bokeh server?
Perhaps let me know where the code for the 4gb of ocean data example is.

Comment: For as far as i know they dont use Bokeh to do the downsampling, but only use Bokeh to display/serve the downsampled data to the plot. Perhaps they use Dask\Blaze to do the actual work, or their 'datashader' (see the Bokeh webinar) . It would be nice to have this or a similar example working, its a great use case.

Comment: I'm working on making a Bokeh server version of a downsampling data, but there are only so many hours in the day, and an infinite list of todos. :) In the mean time, much better docs: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html better examples: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app and live gallery: http://demo.bokehplots.com for general server use

Comment: Also the DataShader repo is now public in the Bokeh org, but it is undergoing a major refactor. Expect more news on DataShader in the next month or so.

Answer (score 0):

That demo showed off custom downsampling code written for a very old version of Bokeh and Bokeh Server. Nowadays, Datashader provides automatic downsampling integrated fully with Bokeh via the high-level [HoloViews](https://holoviews.org) package.  HoloViews creates a Bokeh object with callbacks already set up for zoom and pan events, calling Datashader to regrid/downsample the data as needed. There should be plenty of examples to follow online now, such as the [Datashader LANDSAT](https://examples.pyviz.org/landsat/landsat.html) example or the [HoloViz Advanced Dashboards](http://holoviz.org/tutorial/Advanced_Dashboards.html) tutorial. Or just see the [Datashader](https://datashader.org) website.